# AngularJS Function Trigger Reason

Tags: angularjs

I am following the basic AngularJS tutorials at 'http://angularjs.org/' but I am slightly confused about the reason behind certain functions being triggered.

The their ToDo List app, they have the follows JS within the controller:

```
$scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
        count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
};
```

Which is linked to the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
  [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, when a checkbox is selected/deselected, I don't see how/where the $scope.remaining function is triggered to then update the values in the UI. There are other scope functions, but they don't seem to get called in this scenario, so what is special about this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `remaining`  is used in an Expression (e.g. `{{}}`) angular creates watches for these expressions. So everytime a digest loop happens your function get called.

Comment: So does this mean that any expression present within the ng-controller="TodoCtrl", will automatically get triggered when anything model related gets updated for that controller?

Comment: @envio only the functions that you wrap in {{}} or that you use in ng-* directives